# How can I avoid overflow/underflow when computing the euclidean norm of a vector?

Tags: r, overflow, underflow

I was trying to use `log` and then take the `exp`, but that makes only sense if I deal with products or divisions. One would usually define

```
Euclidean_Norm <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))
```

But I can't handle overflow/underflow. I was thinking to implement

```
Euklidean_Norm2 <- function(x) log(exp(sqrt(sum(x^2))))
```

If I take for example

```
c(34212432, 21343210940, 5412359103)
```

I get `Inf` with `Euklidean_Norm2` and the `Euklidean_Norm` does not work. But it should be representable in R, since

```
sqrt(34212432^2 + 21343210940^2 + 5412359103^2)
[1] 22018797760
```

I am looking for a way to avoid this kind of overflows. I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the issue occurring

Comment: I have a simple implementation `EuklideanDistance <- function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)) ` and i want to figure out a way to avoid overflow/underflow. But i don't know how to approach this problem

Comment: The overflow comes from the part `exp(...)` To avoid it with your function you can do: `m <- mean(x);
m*Euklidean_Norm2(x/m)` (or you put this operation in the function definition) ... a variant: `m <- max(abs(x));
m*Euklidean_Norm2(x/m)`